# conditional validation rule..Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I need help on the below requirement. I have 3 fields -

1. Action Owner - Lookup to User.
2. Task Executioner - Lookup to User.
3. End Date - Date Field

If Action Owner & Task Executioner are equal then End Date can be editable.

If Action Owner & Task Executioner are not equal then only Action Owner can edit the End Date field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Validation rule on the end date field to make sure the Action owner is the one editing, or (according to your requirements) if the action owner and task executioner are the same before updating or saving the record.
you should go: setup-> Object_where_the_fields_are -> custom fields -> End Date -> validation rules...
and the code would be something like this:

```
OR( Action_Owner__r.Id  <>  Task_Executioner__r.Id  , $User.Id  <>   Action_Owner__r.Id )
```

This is: If the action owner and the task executioner are not the same then show an error message OR if the logged in user is not the same as the action owner then show the error as well.
This makes sure that the end date is only editable by the action owner or when owner and executioner are the same